# Eclipse RCP: is there a refresh interval for views?

Tags: eclipse, svn, refresh, rcp, talend

I have a problem with Talend (built with Eclipse RCP): the SVN is checked every second for new files.
After having a look at Talend files, I had isolated a view (class RepoRefreshAction) which seems to update SVN.

I wonder if it is possible that an Eclipse RCP view has a default refresh interval of one second, and if this delay could be changed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing refresh types in `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace` :

you have :

- Refresh using native hooks or polling
- Refresh on access

But it's hard to answer your question if we don't know what exactly you want to achieve (is the refresh too fast, and consume too much system resource ?)
Plus, I don't know how the view is made (I believe it's `RepoViewCommonViewer` or `RepoViewCommonNavigator`), and which Interface is used (I'm using `IResourceChangeListener` for listening to workspace changes)
[explanation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-9.htm)